# Which metrics are exported by DropwizardMetrics (Prometheus client)?

Tags: dropwizard, prometheus

I have implemented a web service using [Dropwizard](https://www.dropwizard.io).
It runs on [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) and we use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) for logging there. 
The web service exports [Dropwizard Metrics](https://metrics.dropwizard.io) using the [Java client implementation](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java) in [`DropwizardExports.java`](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java/blob/master/simpleclient_dropwizard/src/main/java/io/prometheus/client/dropwizard/DropwizardExports.java).

This is the relevant code:

```
private void registerMetrics(Environment environment) {
    CollectorRegistry collectorRegistry = CollectorRegistry.defaultRegistry;
    new DropwizardExports(environment.metrics()).register(collectorRegistry);

    environment.admin().addServlet("metrics", new MetricsServlet(collectorRegistry))
            .addMapping("/metrics");
}
```

I cannot find a reference documenting which metrics are exported exactly and their specific purpose. Even though I can look at the output and figure out most of it, there does not seem to be a comprehensive documentation. The code is not simple enough (for me) to look it up either.

Am I missing something?
I should mention that I am quite new to the Prometheus ecosystem. A pointer to a standard/default that is implemented by `DropwizardExports` might also help.

Comment: What URL prometheus metrics are available ?

Answer (score 0):

DropwizardExports exposes whatever metrics are using that Dropwizard metrics instrumentation environment, so you should look at the Dropwizard documentation to see what they mean.

Comment: I acknowledge that I might have been searching in the wrong place. However, it looks like Dropwizard does not have a documentation about what metrics it exposes either.

Comment: What URL prometheus metrics are available ?